# C++ MFC реализовать проверку на запуск программы с параметром

Tags: c++, mfc

Подскажите как можно простым способом реализовать проверку, что приложение запускается с параметром. То есть если нет параметра выводить ошибку, если совпадает то запускаться.

C++ MFC

Есть какие-нибудь примеры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `ParseCommandLine`

Пример:

```
NewComandLineInfo.h


class CNewCommandLineInfo : public CCommandLineInfo
{
public:
    CString m_sHostAddr;
    UINT    m_nPort;

    void ParseParam(LPCTSTR lpszParam, BOOL bFlag, BOOL bLast);
};
NewComandLineInfo.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CommandLineInfoEx.h"

void CNewCommandLineInfo::ParseParam(LPCTSTR lpszParam, BOOL bFlag, BOOL bLast)
{
    if(bFlag) {
        CString sParam(lpszParam);
        if (sParam.Left(2) == "h:") {
            m_sHostAddr = sParam.Right(sParam.GetLength() - 2);
            return;
        }

        if (sParam.Left(2) == "p:") {
            CString sTemp;

            sTemp = sParam.Right(sParam.GetLength() - 2);
            m_nPort = atoi(sTemp);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Call the base class to ensure proper command line processing
    CCommandLineInfo::ParseParam(lpszParam, bFlag, bLast);
}
We also need to modify the CWinApp derived class to include our special command line processing:

// Example.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the application.
//

#include "NewCommandLineInfo.h"

...

BOOL CExampleApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    // Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
    // and user-defined flags. The CCommandLine class has been replaced
    CNewCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
    ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

    // Access the variables if needed
    CString sHostAddr = cmdInfo.m_sHostAddr;
    UINT nPort = cmdInfo.m_nPort;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetCommandLineW + CommandLineToArgvW в любом месте где вы хотите сделать эту проверку. Вторая из функций возвращает в одном из параметров число параметров командной строки, которое вы и можете проверять.